# Outlook Mailbox Microsoft Login Asking OTP Verification In Robot Framework

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, office365, robotframework, one-time-password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmuey.jpg)

I have tried to open mail from my Outlook 365 mailbox to upload the documents, but it is asking OTP verification to Microsoft outlook 365 login using the robot framework.
How do I verify OTP from my own mobile to log in Outlook 365 mailbox in the robot framework? Also, what kind of keywords and libraries do I need to install to touch the Outlook mailbox to upload documents from email?

*** Settings ***
Documentation   To validate the Outlook Mailbox Functionality
Library         SeleniumLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem
Library         BuiltIn
Library         ImapLibrary

*** Keywords ***
Email Verification
Open Browser    https://outlook.office.com/    Chrome

```
Open Mailbox    host=outlook.office.com    user=my email id    password=secret
${LATEST} =    Wait For Email    sender=my email id    timeout=300
${HTML} =    Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
Should Contain    ${HTML}    Your email address has been updated
Close Mailbox
```